# Why is doctest skipping tests on imported methods?

Tags: python-3.x, doctest

I have a python module `some_module` with an `__init__.py` file that imports methods, like this:

```
from .some_python_file import some_method
```

`some_method` has a docstring that includes doctests:

```
def some_method():
    """
    >>> assert False
    """
```

But when I run `doctest` on the module, it passes even if the tests should fail.

```
import some_module
# How do I get this to consistently fail, regardless of whether
# `some_module.some_method` was declared inline or imported?
assert doctest.testmod(some_module).failed == 0
```

If I instead define `some_method` within the `__init__.py` file, the doctest correctly fails.

Why are these two situations behaving differently? The method is present and has the same `__doc__` attribute in both cases.

How do I get doctest to run the tests defined in the dostrings of methods that were imported into the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Objects imported into the module are not searched.

See docs on [which docstrings are examined](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#which-docstrings-are-examined).

You can can inject the imported function into the module's `__test__` attribute to have imported objects tested:

```
__test__ = {'some_method': some_method}
```

Comment: Ah, well that explains the behavior. Is there a way to work around this limitation? I *want* the behavior where it searches the imported docstrings.

Comment: It looks I can define `__test__ = {name1: obj1, name2: obj2, ...}` for each imported object and that works?

Comment: @CraigGidney Yes, I was going  to add that (already did now). This tells doctest to explicitly test doc strings in the enumerated objects in the dict.

Answer (score 2):

In Python a module is define by a single file and in your case `some_python_file` is a module while `__init__` is another one. Doctest has a check to run tests only for examples reachable from the module which can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6ec2fb42f93660810952388e5c4018c197c17c8c/Lib/doctest.py#L1000).

The best way to see this behaviour in practice is to use [PDB](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) and `pdb.set_trace()` right before you call `doctest.testmod(some_module)` and step inside to follow the logic.

LE:
Doctest ignores imported methods per [this comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6ec2fb42f93660810952388e5c4018c197c17c8c/Lib/doctest.py#L857). If you want to be able to run your test you should probably define a main function in your module and run the test test with `python some_module.py`. You can follow [this example](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6ec2fb42f93660810952388e5c4018c197c17c8c/Lib/doctest.py#L857).

To achieve your expected behaviour you need to manually create a `__test__` dict in your init file:

```
from .some_python_file import some_method

__test__ = {"some_method": some_method}
```

See [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#which-docstrings-are-examined) as well.

Comment: This is useful information but it still doesn't explain why, if I imported a method from another module, that method's docstring is not considered part of the importing module. It also doesn't address the followup question of how to get the doctest to actually run when starting from the importing module without knowledge of the internal implementation details like whether a method is defined inline or imported.

Comment: Hey @CraigGidney I updated my answer with more info, there is a workaround to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question because I was hacking a `__doc__` attribute of an imported object.

````py
from foo import bar
bar.__doc__ = """
>>> assert True
"""

and I was also wondering why the doctest of bar did not get executed by the doctest runner.

The previously given answer to add a `__test__` mapping solved it for good.

```python
__test__ = dict(bar=bar.__doc__)
````

I think the explanation for this behaviour is the following. If you are using a library, lets say NumPy, you do not want all of their doctests to be collected and run in your own code.
Simply, because it would be redundant.
You should trust the developers of the library to (continuously) test their code, so you do not have to do it.

If you have tests defined in your own code, you should have a test collector (e.g. pytest) descend into all files of your project structure and run these.
You would end up testing all doctests in used libraries, which takes a lot of time. So the decision to ignore imported doctests is very sane.